# How to find out which class I'm currently in in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

A rather simple question that I'm sure there's an answer to, I just can't seem to find it by searching

Sometimes I'm looking at or writing some code I want to double check or find out which class I'm in, is there an easier way I can find out without scrolling up to the `class` line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Navigate` | `Select In...` | **Project View** or **File Structure**, or you can keep Project or Structure view visible with the **Autoscroll from Source** option enabled.

It's also possible to use `Navigate` | **File Structure** for a pop-up showing your current position.

Comment: Thanks, I can't seem to find the Autoscroll from source option though?

Comment: Ah thank you, I found it but its got its own button under Structure. Does exactly what I wanted as I usually have the structure pane open all the time.

Comment: The File Structure view is quite clunky; is there no way to obtain a breadcrumb view in python, like one has when editing XML/HTML (ie http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/navigating-with-breadcrumbs.html) ? I can't find any information about this, which is a bit baffling; surely it's possible to implement, otherwise the File Structure view would also be impossible to implement.

Comment: I think it is now called "Always select opened element" (instead of Autoscroll from source) under Structure that highlights the current method in the Structure pane.

Answer (score 26):

Try `ALT+Q`, or Mac: `Ctrl + Shift + Q` for Mac as described in the [PyCharm docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/viewing-current-caret-location.html)

Comment: Mac: Ctrl + Shift + Q

Comment: If you're in a method and a method header is out of the viewport, it displays just the method header, not class.

Comment: But can you navigate to that point as well? Ideally with next / previous class shortcut, much like Alt + Up / Down for functions.

Comment: Is it possible to show this information permanently in the upper part of the editor window?

Comment: @JustAC0der now it shows by default always under the editor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45708386/895245

Answer (score 13):

**Breadcrumb bar just under editor**

As of Pycharm 2017.02, there is a breadcrumb navigation under every editor window that shows information like:

```
ClassName > FunctionName > for i in range(): > if True:
```

You can also click to go to any of those points in the code.

Answer (score 1):

For mac it is: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `q`.